# How to read bytes of a local image file in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: image, dart, base64, byte, flutter

I would like to use a placeholder image file that I've added to my code as `"assets/placeholder.png"`, but I'm getting a File not found error.  This is how I'm doing it from the dartlang documentation...

```
var bytes = await new File('assets/placeholder.png').readAsBytes();
String base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
```

The `bytes` variable errors every time. How can I save the bytes of a locally saved image file?

Comment: You may want to use `Image.asset("assets/placeholder.png") instead

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With Flutter environment, you have to use `AssetBundle` if you want to access to your assets (https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/).

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;


ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/placeholder.png');
```

Comment: Any idea on how to then turn bytes into a BASE64 string?  My CryptoUtils extension above isn't working.

Comment: yes sorry, you should use BASE64 from "dart:convert", https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-convert/BASE64-constant.html

Comment: Please what if the file is from local storage?

Comment: As @X09 mentioned, this implementation doesnt work for loading images from local storage. I used this and first it works but if you load the image from a folder that has a space on the path, it wont work. So be careful

Answer (score 19):

In dart Uint8List is equal to byte[].

1. Create one function and pass file path, It will return Bytes.

   ```
   Future<Uint8List> _readFileByte(String filePath) async {
       Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
       File audioFile = new File.fromUri(myUri);
       Uint8List bytes;
       await audioFile.readAsBytes().then((value) {
       bytes = Uint8List.fromList(value); 
       print('reading of bytes is completed');
     }).catchError((onError) {
         print('Exception Error while reading audio from path:' +
         onError.toString());
     });
     return bytes;
   }
   ```
2. Now call the function in to get bytes of file.

   ```
   try{
     Uint8List audioByte;
     String myPath= 'MyPath/abc.png';
     _readFileByte(myPath).then((bytesData) {
       audioByte = bytesData;
     //do your task here 
     });
   } catch (e) {
      // if path invalid or not able to read
     print(e);
   }
   ```
3. If you want base64String then use below code:

   String audioString = base64.encode(audioByte);

for base64 import 'dart:convert';

I hope it will help!

Comment: downvoted because the suggested solution adds only noise to what was essentially already correctly stated in the question (`File('...').readAsBytes()`), and what was added was not relevant to the question. for those taking this suggested answer as an example, to read and map (then) data from a Future, you can just assign the result of await ... then() directly to a variable, like `var result = await someFunc().then(...)`, so you don't need to declare the variable outside the scope of the callback, and then assign to it.

Comment: I declare the variable outside because if we can use it later before catch block.

Comment: futures can return errors, which can be handled with `myFunc().then(processValue).catchError(handleError)`, see https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling :-)

Answer (score 9):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

...

ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.png');

Uint8List bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

String base64Image = base64.encode(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to read file byte by byte:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  readFileByteByByte().then((done) {
    print('done');
  });
  print('waiting...');
  print('do something else while waiting...');
}

Future<bool> readFileByteByByte() async {
  //final fileName = 'C:\\code\\test\\file_test\\bin\\main.dart'; // use your image file name here
  final fileName = Platform.script.toFilePath(); //this will read this text file as an example
  final script = File(fileName);
  final file = await script.open(mode: FileMode.read);

  var byte;
  while (byte != -1) {
    byte = await file.readByte();
    if (byte == ';'.codeUnitAt(0)) { //check if byte is semicolon
      print(byte);
    }
  }
  await file.close();
  return (true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if need read some bytes, use this

```
Future<Uint8List> readFileBytes(String path, int len) async {
    final File file = File(path);
    RandomAccessFile fileOpen = await file.open(mode: FileMode.read);

    int count = 0;
    List<int> bytes = [];
    int byte;

    while (byte != -1 && count < len) {
      byte = fileOpen.readByteSync();
      bytes.add(byte);
      count++;
    }

    await fileOpen.close();
    return Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
  }
```