# How to load image from decodeImage(File('assets/logo.png').readAsBytesSync()); in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm creating a pdf with flutter using a 'pdf' package. So I want to insert an image in pdf. The problem is that then I don't know how to load an image from assets in the 'Image' package which is recommended to use in the 'pdf' package.
Refrence:https://pub.dev/packages/pdf :pdf package refrence and 
https://pub.dev/packages/image: image package refrence

I have tried some code but none work
`pdf.dart`

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imgs;
final img1 = imgs.decodeImage(File('assets/logo.png').readAsBytesSync());
Image(PdfImage(
                      pdf.document,
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      image: img1.data.buffer.asUint8List(),
                    ))
```

I have image in assests folder in project and I also have it in `pubspec.yaml` file

I am expecting to load the image from the assets folder using the 'image' package.
Or is there another way to load an image in 'pdf' package.

Some of the error when I use the above code:

```
E/PDFView (13223): load pdf error
E/PDFView (13223): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125727/6300600) on how to load image from asset bundle. `File('assets/logo.png')` will attempt to find that file on the phone's filesystem which is not where your asset bundle is.

---

Alternatively if you also have the [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package installed:

```
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show AssetImage;

final pdf = Document(deflate: zlib.encode);

PdfImage logoImage = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
  pdf: pdf.document,
  image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
);
```

Wrap it with the `Image` widget from `package:pdf/widgets.dart` then add it to your document:

```
pdf.addPage(
  MultiPage(
    header: Image(logoImage),
    build: Container(),
    footer: Container(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I'm using ``package:pdf/pdf.dart`` does it also have pdfImageFromImageProvider().what should I do to use in pdf/pdf.dart package

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125727/6300600) on how to load image from asset bundle. `File('assets/logo.png')` will attempt to find that file on the phone's filesystem which is not where your asset bundle is

Comment: When I add 'printing' package and run app  then it is showing error  :```[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/painting/codec.cc(207)] Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.```